# image fadein without blink with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, image, fade

I am trying to fade in an image when I click on a link, but that gives me a "blink" on every fade. Is there anyway to avoid this blink and just have a clean fadeIn?

This is my current code:

```
function changeMortar(mortar) {
     var html = '<img src="http://www.randerstegl.dk/fileadmin/fugefarver/GFXSharedMortars/fuge'+mortar+'.png" width="500" height="300">'                    
        $("#fuge-color").hide().html(html).fadeIn('slow');
    }​
```

I have made this example
http://jsfiddle.net/BHCam/14/

It fades to white and then into the mortar I selected. What I want is to have my selected mortar, fade over the old mortar.

Comment: its working fine on my crome brower,In which browser are u testing?

Comment: Hmm.. I am testing in Google Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes to your code. Try like this in HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
   <img src="http://www.randerstegl.dk/fileadmin/fugefarver/GFXSharedMortars/fugeGraa.png" alt="" class="active" width="500" height="300"/>
   <img src="http://www.randerstegl.dk/fileadmin/fugefarver/GFXSharedMortars/fugeAnthrazit.png" width="500" height="300" />

</div>
<a href="#" class="change-mortar-link" onclick="slideSwitch();">Change mortar</a>
```

In CSS:

```
#slideshow {
   position:relative;
   height:350px;
}
#slideshow IMG {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:8;
}
#slideshow IMG.active {
   z-index:10;
}
#slideshow IMG.last-active {
   z-index:9;
}
```

And The JavaScript code:

```
function slideSwitch() {
   var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

   if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

   var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

   $active.addClass('last-active');

   $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
      .addClass('active')
      .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
          $active.removeClass('active last-active');
     });
  }
```

And in [here](http://jonraasch.com/blog/a-simple-jquery-slideshow) you can find more information. And [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mahsa_999/gQjsS/1/) is the running example in JsFiddle.

Answer (score 4):

Blinking and other artifacts like this are likely caused by your browser or your graphics card drivers, so there's not much you can do beside checking your graphics settings tuning or upgrading your machine components. Your example fades smoothly here.

Comment: Oh.. I think I expressed myself wrong - sorry about that. It fades to white and then into the mortar I selected. What I want is to have my selected mortar, fade over the old mortar

Answer (score 1):

Just change it to

```
 $("#fuge-color").hide().fadeIn('slow'); //use slow,fast,1000,2000,3000
```

Choose your best result

Answer (score 1):

Could you try with `animate`:

```
function changeMortar(mortar) {
 var $html = '<img src="http://www.randerstegl.dk/fileadmin/fugefarver/GFXSharedMortars/fuge'+mortar+'.png" width="500" height="300">'                    
     $("#fuge-color").animate({ opacity: 0.8 }, 'fast', function(){
          $(this).html($html).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 'fast');
     });
}
```